# Finding similar values pandas

Tags: python, pandas, compare

I have a dataframe that I am trying to get the matching values between two columns.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['thomas', 'tommy'], ['nickolas', 'nicky'], ['johnathan', 'johnny']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Nickname'])
```

I have tried .isin method in pandas.

`df['matches'] = df['Nickname'].isin(df['Name'])`

This is the desired output:

```
# Desired output
matching = ['tom','nick','john']
```

Basically I want to return True if it should return the similar characters from each column.

Comment: what is the logic? How can you get `tom` from `thomas` and `tommy`? Why wouldn't you get `johnn` for `johnathan` and `johnny`?

Comment: Because the way the alphabet and the word is spelled. Thomas contains the word tom in it and Johnny has John in it.

Comment: No, `thomas` does **not** contain `tom`: `'tom' in 'thomas'` -> `False` unlike `'john' in 'johnny'` -> `True`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I totally missed it but if I understand you correctly and assuming you need the common letters between *names/nicknames* with a fixed gap between consecutive matches as a constraint, you can try this approach that will [`get_matching_blocks`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_matching_blocks) :

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def match(w1, w2, D, ref="Name"):
    w = w1 if ref=="Name" else w2
    matches = SequenceMatcher(None, w1, w2).get_matching_blocks()[:-1]
    tmp = pd.DataFrame([(m.a, m.size) for m in matches]) # starts/sizes
    idx = (tmp[0].sub(tmp[0].add(tmp[1]).shift()).fillna(False)
                 .le(D).cummin()[::-1].idxmax())
    blocks = [w[m.a:m.a+m.size] for m in matches]
    return "".join(blocks[:idx+1]) if D>0 else max(blocks, key=len)

# D is the maximum gap between two consecutive matches
# if D=1, this ensures to match for e.g tho and to and not them and tm

cols = ["Name", "Nickname"]
df["matches (GAP=0)"] = [match(w1, w2, D=0) for (w1, w2) in df[cols].to_numpy()]
df["matches (GAP=1)"] = [match(w1, w2, D=1) for (w1, w2) in df[cols].to_numpy()]
```

Output :

```
print(df)

        Name Nickname matches (GAP=0) matches (GAP=1)
0     thomas    tommy              om             tom
1   nickolas    nicky            nick            nick
2  johnathan   johnny            john            john
```

Comment: I was waiting for OP to clarify but that's more or less the logic I had in mind. However, a match without gap should give you the longest string (`om`) ;)

Comment: I made a small adjustment to handle that and I hope there won't be any more flaws ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could go about this by implementing a function that checks letter-by-letter:

```
def common_chars(str1, str2):
common = []
for char in str1:
    if char in str2:
        common.append(char)
        str2 = str2.replace(char, '', 1)
return ''.join(common)

df['Matching'] = df.apply(lambda row: common_chars(row['Name'], row['Nickname']), axis=1)
```

This will return a 'Matching' column and will give you 'tom' in the case of 'thomas'/'tommy' but will still return 'johnn' in your example's third row.

Comment: `common_chars('penelope', 'lopez')` ;)

Comment: haha great counter example :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def matching(x):
    result = np.intersect1d(list(x.Name), list(x.Nickname)) ### Find common characters
    string = [None]*len(list(x.Name))
    for char in result:
        ### Append common characters to string based on indexing of first string
        string[list(x.Name).index(char)] = char
    string = [i for i in string if i is not None]
    return "".join(string)

df.apply(matching, axis=1)
```

I divided the solution in 2 parts:

1. First finding common characters between 2 strings
2. And then sorting the common characters based on the first or second string

Example:
First string: 'thomas' 
Second string: 'tommy'

Common string: ['m', 'o', 't'] 
First string(list): ['t', 'h', 'o', 'm', 'a', 's']

Now based on indexing of First string(list) reorganize the Common string
['t', 'o', 'm']